# How do I load local files to a front-end html5 runing on apache2 localhost

Tags: html, apache, localhost, gnu

I can't realize how to load a video located on my Desktop on a front-end code I have in my localhost runing on `apache2`.
I tried: `file:///localhost/home/Desktop/video.mp4` , but It doesn't work because for sure, I'm not right.

Thanks!

Comment: The file should be on your server (even if your server is running on localhost). What you are attempting to do won't work as it breaks the security model of the browser... being able to access files on the local computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file** protocol loads local files, first you have to use the **http** protocol, then apache will look for files in your document root directory so all paths will be relative to the document root, so first you have to set the correct document root, then use the correct protocol.

it would be like `http://localhost/video.mp4`